# I have app called Typing Game that's check text and calculate time?

Tags: java, android, methods, timer

[image]

I used this in onCreate Methods when I click ok on dialog the time starts:

```
    private static final int Ready_Dialog=1;

private static final int CORRECT_DIALOG = 2;

private static final int INCORRECT_DIALOG = 3;

private static double startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

private static double endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      showDialog(Ready_Dialog);

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

            EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

            String input=et.getText().toString();

            TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

             String except=tv.getText().toString();

            if(input.equals(except))

            {

                removeDialog(CORRECT_DIALOG);
                endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                showDialog(CORRECT_DIALOG);
            }
            else
            {

                removeDialog(INCORRECT_DIALOG);
                showDialog(INCORRECT_DIALOG);
            }   
        }
    });
```

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
double time;

```
    String Message = null;

    if (id == Ready_Dialog){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // this is the message to display

        builder.setMessage(R.string.ready);

        // this is the button to display

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){

                // this will hide the dialog

                startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

                dialog.cancel();

            }

        });

        return builder.create();


        }

    if(id==INCORRECT_DIALOG)

    Message="You get it wrong !Click Yes to play again ";

    else

        if(id==CORRECT_DIALOG)

        {

            time=((endTime-startTime/100)/10);


            BigDecimal db = new BigDecimal(time).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

            Message="That's right ! That took you"+time+" seconds! Click Yes to play again.";

        }

AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

AlertDialog.Builder builder1=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setMessage(Message);

builder1.setPositiveButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

    @Override

    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1){
        // close App

        finish();
    }

});
```

but the dialog displayed as second looks to the Pic in question
like when you touch "Submit" Button , the Toast message will say " That's Right ! , It took you 3.2 Second" As Example .

Comment: I want this App to display time like this 3.15s not same in pic .Is there any way to solve?

Comment: I think he is trying to figure out how to Format the number :-)

Comment: @user3025186 see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is set your precision.  Below I told it to found up half way and display only two decimal points.  If you want more then change the 2 to something else.

```
double time =((endTime-startTime/100)/10);
BigDecimal db = new BigDecimal(time).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

You may want to see the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) to see all the other fun things you can do with `BigDecimal`.

Comment: If your having the same problem there is something your not telling us that we need to compensate for.  Can you provide more code?

Comment: looks please to more code @buzzsawddog

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are dividing 'startTime' by 100 but not 'endTime'. Try:

```
double time = ((endTime - startTime) / 1000);
```

You may also want to do a search on printing floating point numbers in Java so you can get the formatting right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple trick

```
int time = ((endTime-startTime/100)/10) *10;
```

whenever you want to display time do this

```
(float) (time /10)
```

if time is for example 3.5xxxxx (x are digits we don't care and discard)
the first line will assign 35 to time, and the second like will always return 3.5 the rest of the digits are discarded when you initialize time